# Rails version not shown post installation

Tags: 10.04, rails, gems

I had installed **rubygems 1.8** and further on I had installed the rails 2.0.2 gem.

When I tried to view the rails version installed through the command `rails -v`

It didn't work.. I am unable to figure out why I am getting an **"invalid option"** on executing the command `rails -v` ( Please refer the below for the same).

```
mohnish@mohnish-laptop:~/Downloads$ ruby -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2010-01-10 patchlevel 249) [i486-linux]
mohnish@mohnish-laptop:~/Downloads$ gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

actionmailer (2.0.2)
actionpack (2.0.2)
activerecord (2.0.2)
activeresource (2.0.2)
activesupport (2.0.2)
rails (2.0.2)
rake (0.8.7)
mohnish@mohnish-laptop:~/Downloads$ rails -v
getopt: invalid option -- 'v'
Terminating...
mohnish@mohnish-laptop:~/Downloads$
```

Could you please help me out on this regard..

Please note I am currently not making use of the ruby version manager(rvm). Please let me know if I could get a solution once I install the rvm.

Thanks for your help..

Comment: I find that most of my headaches go away when I use RVM. good luck with the package manager. ><

Comment: What happens if you enter `which rails`?

Comment: @pdr: I get: "/usr/bin/rails" on typing the command "which rails"

Answer (score 1):

You can just install the [rails package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/rails)

```
sudo apt-get install rails
```

on my system:

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2010-06-23 patchlevel 299) [i686-linux]
$ rails -v
Rails 2.3.5
```

Your version numbers will be a bit lower than mine because I am using Ubuntu 10.10.

Comment: I tried out the link... It says that you have a rails package already installed.

Comment: Some wise person has said never to install the Rails package from the Ubuntu repo.

Comment: @mgj - that's strange. You could try `sudo apt-get remove rails` then  `sudo gem uninstall rails` then `sudo apt-get install rails` to revert to the repository version only. @Zabba - that 'wise' person was wrong. You should always use repository packages unless there is a good reason not to, like you need a specific version that isn't packages.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I would consider that option as a last resort. I am trying to figure another way out in the mean time.